# How to make a generic function usable?

Tags: typescript

I understand what generic types do, but I don't get the point. If I have a function:

```ts
function safeCount<T>(a:T):T {
  return a + 2
}
```

It will only work if I pass a number to it. But what if I pass an object or an array? Because of the generic type, TypeScript won't return an error, and the app will crash. I know generics must be very useful, but I just don't see why for the moment. Could you please explain to me why `safeCount()` would benefit from `<T>` here?

Comment: That example *doesn't* benefit from a generic type. Look at [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) to see some examples that do.

Comment: "Typescript won't return an error" --- won't it? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIbAKYGE7igHgBUA+AClQC5CBKKxAbwFgAoRNxAJwyhA6VUQBqRACYWbAL5A

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms pointed out, typescript compiler does complain and returns an error.

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'number'
```

Generics aren't useful everywhere, there are some use cases for them and if used correctly they can be pretty useful and make your code more organized and simpler.

Look at the below example from the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

Imagine you want to write an [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) (a function that simply return it's input), one way is to write it this way:

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
  return arg;
}
```

Now if you have:

```
const output = identity("hello")
// output type is any.
```

But the right way to define the identity function is like below:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}
```

Now we have:

```
const output = identity("hello")
// output type is 'string'
```